# Write a recursive version of the function reverse(s), which reverses the string s in place.I cant seem to find the error

Tags: c, string, recursion

This is a question from K and R. And when i try compiling it its says Segmentation fault (core dumped). I cant seem to find the error however.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

This does your basic swap

```
 void swap(char s[], int i, int j) {
    char temp;
    temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = temp;
}


void reverse(char s[]){
    int i, j;

    if (i == 0) 
        j = strlen(s)-1;
    swap(s, i, j);
    j--;
    i++;
    // Here is where the problem arises. When i don't call the function here the program works perfectly  (The limitation being only the first and last char get swapped) otherwise it gives an error saying segmentation fault
    if (i < j)
        reverse(s);
}

int main () {
    int i;
    char s[10] = "hello";
    reverse(s);
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: `    int i, j;

    if (i == 0) ` i is Indefinite

Answer (score 1):

To start with, when you declare `i` inside `reverse` you don't assign a value to it, so its value will be random. So when you use `i` in the comparison it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I did that intentionally if you notice I've left j uninitialized.
Thats cause I figured when you declare an integer and don't initialize it ,by default it takes the value of 0. (I may be wrong but check out this snippet of code)

    #include <stdio.h>
    main() {
      int i;
      printf("%d", i);
      return 0;
    }

WHAT YOU SAY IS CORRECT BUT THEN THE OUTPUT OF THIS CODE PUZZLES ME .

Comment: @the_lost_one Nope , that's not correct . Only variable defined with some specific storage class take the value of 0 like `extern` and `static`. Compile with -Wall option. And it wonders me how you get 0 , it should print garbage.

Comment: Extern did the trick. Initializing it outside took care of the prob thanks guys!!:) 

@PHIfounder , But i did get 0 without initializing on compiling.

Comment: @the_lost_one Then there must be some problem with your compiler or system .

Comment: @the_lost_one The behavior of unspecified behavior is that it's unspecified. Anything could happen, it's simply not predictable.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are uninitialized in function reverse.

When you do this:

`if (i==0)`

you are comparing an uninitialized variable  with zero ,So `j` also remains uninitialized.

Even if you initialized them in reverse it won't work out because `reverse` is recursively called.

Just suppose you do initialized `i` and `j` in reverse like this :

```
void reverse (char s[])
{
 int i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1;
   .....
   ...
 reverse(s);
}
```

Since it is called recursively every time you pass i & j to swap they are again initialized
to `0` and `strlen(s)-1` , so it would be better to initialize them in `main()` and pass them to reverse like the way given below.

I think you should better try something like this :

```
void reverse(char s[], int i, int j)
{
  swap( s , i , j);
  --j;
  i++;
  if (i < j)
    reverse( s , i , j);
}
```

And then in do something like this in `main()` :

```
  char s[] = "hello";
  int i = 0 , j = strlen(s)-1;
  reverse( s , i , j);
  printf("%s" , s);
```

Comment: @the_lost_one You didn't tell if it worked for you :) always remember to give us feedback and if possible accept the answer you are satisfied with ...... it helps in making the post better and useful :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swap Function**

```
 void swap(char *s, int i, int j)

{
    char temp;
    temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = temp;
    printf("swap %s\n",s);
}
```

**Reverse Function**

```
void reverse(char *s,int j,int i)
```

here i am passing address so *s and j and i has to be taken from main as we cant initialize variables inside this reverse function as it may cause problems in the terminating condition.You have done the same mistake.*

```
{
    printf("%d\t%d\n",i,j);
    if(i<j)//`base condition`
{
    swap(s, i, j);
    reverse(s,--j,++i);
}
}
```

*--j will decrement in j and ++i will increment in i.Here the preincrement and predecrement is the key*

**main function**

```
    int main ()
{
    int i=0;
    char s[10] = "hello";
    printf("%s\n",s);
    reverse(s,(strlen(s)-1),i);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
hello
0   4
swap oellh
1   3
swap olleh
2   2
olleh
```

Comment: **s is necessary as we are passing the address* , no that's not necessary........ `reverse(s,--j,++i);` that's not  good  or I should say pretty much undefined .

Comment: @PHIfounder how is that undefined?plz can you tell me ?

Comment: Because there is not predefined sequence in that call , the pre-increment can happen before the function call , so it will definitely have side-effects. Google it !! You will most probably get an answer on SO itself .

Comment: @thats why i have use pre...i want to pre-increment it before it is making the recursive call to reverse again

Comment: @PHIfounder That sequencing affects the post order arguments only

Comment: @PHIfounder i have removed the line

Comment: Thanks but just now i have posted the same question on so just to clarify